# How can I let users access a specific attachment?

Tags: attachments

I'm trying to add a XML file to my site that users can access when I give them the url.

www.domain.com/blank01/blank02/file.xml

As of right now, blank01 and blank02 don't exist as pages. Down the road they will have content and links that eventually take you to "file.xml" and others.

But for right now I just want to put this file on my WP and make it accessible to my users when they go to this specifically designated url, but I can't figure out how to.

I tried to upload it to the library, but the file type wasn't accepted, but I fixed that. Once I did get it uploaded to the library, I couldn't change the link.

Also, what do I need to do to make blank01 and blank02 exist without being pages, just categories for now? Or do they have to be pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress (or more precisely its `.htaccess` or alternate web server configuration file) passes through requests to existing files.

The easiest way would be to start at root of your site and (using FTP/SFTP/hosting admin panel/etc):

- create `blank01` folder
- create `blank02` subfolder in it
- place `file.xml` into subfolder

And it should just work, link will point to *real* file and WP won't get involved at all.